# Selenium - Visibility of element in HTML page (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape the following URL: https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/sp/holambra/imovel-comercial_comercial/. It has two pages only. However, there is a button in the bottom which I can locate via XPATH: "//*[contains(@title, "Página anterior")]".

I'm trying to set a variable for when the button is not clickable, like:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@title, "Página anterior")]')))
```

But it returns an element, even if the element is not clickable (I'm testing manually too). Is there any sugestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button is not clickable, it has an attribute called `data-disabled`; otherwise that attribute is missing. The attribute has no value, but if you use the following CSS Selector it should grab that element **only** if there is no `data-disabled` attribute:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title="Página anterior"]:not([data-disabled]')
```